# Kittens ate entire bag of treats! Please help

Tags: cats, diet, treats

Today I found a clawed-through empty 6.3oz bag of *Temptations Kitten Chicken and Dairy*. One or both of my kittens F~5m & M ~6M have eaten the entire bag most likely within the past 6 hours. **What should I do? Do they need to see a vet? Emergency Room?**
They already had breakfast. Should I withhold dinner?

I don’t yet see signs of diarrhea and they seem to be acting normal. The kittens are free fed *WholeHearted Grain-Free Chicken Recipe Dry Kitten Food* and each given 2.75oz *WholeHearted Grain-Free Chicken Recipe Flakes in Gravy Wet Kitten Food* twice a day.

Comment: Take a deep breath. Relax. They overindulged in cat treats. Temptations are not only perfectly safe cat treats, they're actually also a food substitute (nutritionally complete).

Comment: Call your vet if you need reassurance, but the most likely outcome is that they'll puke them back up and/or have a reduced appetite at dinner time. And keep the treats well out of reach in the future, they're called "temptations" for a reason. ;) I keep mine in a screw-top plastic jar to prevent these types of incidents.

Answer (score 3):

Like a kid getting into the cookies, this isn't ideal but won't do much if any harm.

In fact, some treats are nutritionally complete enough that a cat could live on them; they're just too expensive and not a well balanced meal. Read the labels.

(I wish I'd realized that last when Harry was in palliative care for cancer. He was not eating well and losing weight, but was still interested in cat treats. I might have been able to give him another month or two if I'd just fed him those.)